# Linux Internal Process for Cat and Grep

Tags: linux, grep, cat

I'm newbie to linux back round process, for example i have the below linux command, Maybe the question will duplicate here but i couldn't find answer so posting it.

```
cat test.txt | grep hello
```

how many back round process(s) will run? It would be great if insight on this.

Comment: `grep hello test.txt`

Comment: Both cat and grep will be a member of the foreground process group, and both will receive keyboard generated signals. So I think we can say no background processes will run here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two processes: *cat* and *grep*.

If you just launch the command line likt that, both processes are **not** background processes. (I guess you are asking background jobs?)

However, this example is not good, since you can just `grep hello test.txt` to save one process.

But if you just want to ask the number of processes, it's fine.

Comment: yeah i wanted to ask number of process, thank you very much.